# How do I vote things up on this site?

Tags: discussion

I would like to vote things and comment on things, but do not know how. Please help.

P.S. I actually do know, but I can't get past Student level because I don't have an actual question to ask yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Asking, answering and suggesting edits doesn't require any reputation

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried reading the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

> Vote up Moderation privilegePrivilege type:
>
> Awarded at: 15 reputation
>
> What is voting up? Voting up is how the community indicates which
>   questions and answers are most useful and appropriate.
>
> When should I vote up? Whenever you encounter a question, answer or
>   comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.
>
> How do I vote up? Click the large up arrow to the left of a post, or
>   the small up arrow to the left of a comment.
>
> You can undo your vote by clicking the same button you used to vote,
>   so click the up arrow to undo an upvote or the down arrow to undo a
>   downvote. To change a vote from up to down, click the down arrow, and
>   vice versa. Votes can only be changed for a short period of time, so
>   be careful with those clicks!

Comment: Nope, they didn't think about it yet.  Duplicating a message that is guaranteed to change Real Soon Now is not a good idea.  Just post the link if you want to help.